# Django 1.6 - Programmatically create groups and permissions

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.6

I am building a Django project that will have Users and Providers. Think of a Provider as a business that can have 1+ employees and 0+ customers. I am currently planning to use the same user model for both employees and customers (if this is problematic, please let me know).

I successfully created a customer user model and am now trying to figure out how to create Providers. I want a user who creates a new Provider (think of this as the business owner or manager) to be able to create customer roles and permissions. I was planning to offer three standards: admin, employee, customer. How do I allow an admin of a Provider to create a new role and to define what permissions go along with that role.

StackOverflow has been a tremendous resource as I've taught myself how to use Django but I haven't yet found an answer for this that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you though of using the [Django authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) ?

It provides a group and permission system that can be associated with the `django.contrib.contenttypes` which is the Django content type system. It allows permissions to be associated with models you create (`Provider`s for example).